# C++: Why is the time shown by __TIME__ earlier than doing ctime(&time(NULL))?

Tags: c++

I have the following code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    cout << ctime(&t) << __TIME__;
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I got was something like this:

```
Tue Jul 27 19:04:33 2021
19:04:31
```

In fact, all of my runs showed that the time displayed by `__TIME__` is 2-3 seconds earlier than that by `ctime(&t)`, even though it was being printed later. Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: in general you should read some documentation. Even things that have an obvious name, like "time" are not always obvious. This time you get an unexpected time, next time it might be worse. C++ isn't something you can learn by guessing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__TIME__` is a preprocessor macro that gets replaced by the current time when you compile the code.

`time()` from `ctime` returns the current time when you execute the program.

You will notice that when you run the same program again (without recompiling) the time from `__TIME__` will not change.